# Stripping HTML from C# program that integrates a website into Jira

Tags: c#, html

I am working on a website that is integrated in Jira. The web page has a "description" section. When I write a description on the web page this looks okay, but when it gets imported into Jira , the ticket has html tags in the description:

```
ex: < p > this is the description < p >
```

instead of simply 'this is the description'

Here is the description call in the C# code:

```
var ticket = new Ticket()
{
    Id = 0,
    IsActive = true,
    TicketDescription =
        string.IsNullOrEmpty(issue.Description)
            ? string.Empty
            : issue.Description.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br />"),
    AssignedToId = assignedToUser.SecurityUserId,
    TicketTypeId = type == 0 ? 1 : type,
};
```

what would I need to add to TicketDescription so the html is always stripped ?

Comment: try replacing this `Environment.NewLine` with actual `"\n\r\"`

Answer (score 0):

You can create a string extension which will strip all tags:

```
public static string RemoveHtmlTags(string input)
{
   return Regex.Replace(input, "<.*?>", String.Empty);
}
```

then you can use it like:

```
TicketDescription =
        string.IsNullOrEmpty(issue.Description)
            ? string.Empty
            : issue.Description.RemoveHtmlTags()
```

Comment: this will remove all instances of <*> so you might want a black list instead but this approach may get you going

Comment: Thank you! Where would I declare the public static string method ?

Comment: probably best to create a class called StringExtensions.cs in a common project

Answer (score 0):

I would create an extension method like this:

```
/// Strips all HTML tags from a string
public static string StripHtml(this string html)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(html))
        return html;
    return Regex.Replace(html, @"<(.|\n)*?>", " ").Trim();
}
```

You can customize the replace token at your convenience. In this case I simply used a whitespace.

Then just use it in in place of your `Replace`